# C++ static allocation vs dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, memory-management, variable-length-array

I know the difference between static (determined by compiler) and dynamic (determined at runtime) allocation. What I don't understand is what happens in the case where we have the following code that is executed successfully:
At compilation, we don't know the value of `nbr`, but we have static allocation with `int tab[nbr]`!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nbr;
    cout << "Enter nbr of student in class = ";
    cin >> nbr ;

    int tab[nbr];
    for (int i=0; i < nbr ; i++) {
        tab[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i=0; i < nbr ; i++) {
        cout << tab[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int tab[nbr];` is not valid C++ (it uses VLA extension).

Comment: `int tab[nbr];` would be runtime "allocation", but with automatic storage (basically the stack).

Comment: Yes, `int tab[nbr]` is invalid, but some compilers still allow it (at least with default settings) for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet you show does not conform to any C++ Standard. However, some C++ compilers such as GCC implement [variable length arrays](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html), originally a C99 feature. Whether these are allocated on the stack or the heap is up to the compiler (i.e. an implementation detail).

EDIT: you mention in a comment that your compiler does not produce warnings even with the `-pedantic` flag. Which compiler are you using? GCC 10.1.0 indeed warns: `warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘tab’` on my system.

Answer (score -3):

Well, `in C`,or in most compilers that integrate the language, it works this way (with a slight difference in language implementation between the c compilers because the standard c of the margin for that, so you never know what is part of the standard and what it does part of the specific implementation of c in the specific compiler, without seeing the documentation for the standard): when the compiler knows what the value is, that is, when you define a variable without base on any other value in a decision structure which depends on a dynamic value, it will, as a result, be known by the compiler, however if the opposite is true the truth will be `dynamic allocation`, which fits your case. Simply put, if you know the value of a variable, it is defined at compile time, otherwise, it is execution time, which fits the case of `tab[nbr]` which depends on a `dynamic value`.

You are assuming that the value of the variable is defined by compilation time because you technically know what is in the variable, but you do not know what is in it, but the context of what is in it. It is not the context that matters for the definition if a variable for it becomes runtime or compilation time, but what is inside, the absolute value, that is, raw numbers, bytes or bits you want to call, if the existence the value or its own declaration depends on a number that comes from a variable that is dynamic or compiled.

But without any context of specific programming languages, compiled variables are just values ​​that are replaced by their values ​​defined at the time of compilation, and without any intervention at the time of execution, meanwhile, variables at runtime are loaded into RAM, and administered there, and by the CPU. sThe reason they depend on CPU cycles (which varies a lot, can be checked in the Windows system tab, are measured in Heartz) to be: moved, deleted, and created, it depends on performance, it is bad to CPU and to you.

**In short**, what matters is not the context of what is in the variable at the moment for the variable to be allocated or compiled, but whether the variable depends on a dynamic number or at compile time for its declaration or definition.

the differences are:

- Dynamic variables are managed by the cpu, in the ram, uses to for calculations that depend on values ​​that are not predictable, such as the space allocation delay, or the size of a user input.
- Variables in compilation time are administered by the compiler for
  the purpose of improving performance, so that the cpu does not waste
  time in a calculation where the result is somehow predictable at compile time.

References:

- [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-static-and-dynamic-memory-allocation-in-C)
- [Geek](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-static-allocation-and-stack-allocation/)
- [Table of Diferences between static and runtime variables](http://somnathkayal.blogspot.com/2014/03/difference-between-static-memory.html)

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. So assuming  "int tab[nbr];" is not valid standard C++ , and it's using an extension, i try to disable extensions in clode::block,  But code is still executed successfully.

Comment: By disable extension, i meant , checked the "-pedantic" warnings .  Note i dont have warnings as well. Code is executed without errors and warning .